C# Outlook Web Addin - Appointments
I have created an C# Outlook web addin for outlook web.
My problem is that the addin is not always showing in the apps list.
What usually happens is that I turn on my VS project in the morning, start debug the project and then I dont see the addin.
Then i'll try and find the reason and about 30 minutes later, sometimes without any changes, it pops up in the apps list again.
I have not made any changes to the default files, only changing some titles and so on.
But function-wise, its the out-of-the-box template for a C# outlook web addin.
Another issue i have is that, when it does appear, then if i make changes in the manifest file, ie. Display name, are not reflected right away.
Sometimes they appear after 5-10 debugs sometimes a couple of hours later.
Its just not very consistent like for example a winforms app, where each change is reflected right away in the next debug!
Anybody have experienced the same issues, and what did you do to solve it?
